# Objective-C Random Number

Tags: objective-c, random

I have one piece of code that is giving me some trouble and is confusing.

Here is the piece of code...

```
int r = rand() % 100;
printf("Random number: %u", r);
```

Why does it print 7 every time? According to the book it should print any number 0-100 I believe... am I wrong with this?

Comment: removed irrelevant information. please focus on the question.

Comment: @qegal That isn't a duplicate to this question. It doesn't explain the results being asked about here.

Comment: @rmaddy - That's true. Is there anyway to repeal close votes?

Comment: @qegal Not that I know of. You might want to search over in the "meta" site for discussions on that topic.

Comment: I don't want my question closed... :( I had that happen last time and it deactivated my account.

Comment: oops. I failed to read comments here... just marked as a dup of the question I always use when I forget the name arc4random.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to seed it first:

```
srandom(time(NULL));
```

It is actually better to just use [arc4random](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html):

```
int r = arc4random() % 100;
printf("Random number: %u", r);
```

Comment: Ah... Thank you. That was successful. Why is arc4random better? Just preference or is the delegate just better?

Comment: Or is it just easier this way? Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: `srandom` is for seeding `random`. Use `srand` to seed `rand`. And it is better to use `arc4random_uniform` instead of `arc4random` when you will be apply modulus to the result (like is being done here).

Answer (score 2):

Random numbers are pseudo-random. To make them seem random, they are seeded at arbitrary times based on your design. If you want seeding and "random" number generation to happen simultaneously, use `arc4random` instead, which also provides other benefits.